# mongodb on server automatically shutdowns when i turn off my system

Tags: ubuntu-server, mongodb

i have installed mongoDB on ubuntu server and it works well with my node project. But now it shutdowns automatically and i don't know why it stops
mongodb on server automatically shutdowns when i turn off my system.
how do i solve this issue.
it works well on the server but when i turn off my system and come back again to an api call it shows a response json which saying mongo error.
i am running nodejs project to deal with mongodb and using an ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

How do you start a MongoDB server? If you start it as a process that belongs to you, after disconnecting with the server it will stop. Try disowning this process or run a Docker container with MongoDB database.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually i have solved the issue with an sdk named(pm2) i have run the app using pm2 with two different commands(1. pm2 start app.js, 2. pm2 startup systemd)